# How to convert IEnumerable to ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#

How to convert `IEnumerable` to `ObservableCollection`?

Answer (score 257):

As per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx)

```
var myObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<YourType>(myIEnumerable);
```

This will make a shallow copy of the current IEnumerable and turn it in to a ObservableCollection.

Comment: Is this quicker than using a ForEach loop to insert the items one by one into the collection?

Comment: @Rexxo it will be slightly faster to do it with the constructor. Internally [it is using a `foreach`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs.html#cfaa9abd8b214ecb) to copy the items to the internal collection, however if you do the foreach and call `Add` [it will be going through `InsertItem`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs.html#767bf62bf4a3a7c1) which does a lot of extra stuff that is unessesary when initially filling causing it to be slightly slower.

Comment: Simples and the best answer

Answer (score 84):

1. If you're working with non-generic `IEnumerable` you can do it this way:

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<object> Convert(IEnumerable original)
   {
       return new ObservableCollection<object>(original.Cast<object>());
   }
   ```
2. If you're working with generic `IEnumerable<T>` you can do it this way:

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<T> Convert<T>(IEnumerable<T> original)
   {
       return new ObservableCollection<T>(original);
   }
   ```
3. If you're working with non-generic `IEnumerable` but know the type of elements, you can do it this way:

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<T> Convert<T>(IEnumerable original)
   {
       return new ObservableCollection<T>(original.Cast<T>());
   }
   ```

Answer (score 41):

To make things even more simple you can create an [Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730013/extension-methods) method out of it.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> col)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<T>(col);
    }
}
```

Then you can call the method on every IEnumerable

```
var lst = new List<object>().ToObservableCollection();
```

Comment: Cool answer for a cool question, I add this to pinned answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
ObservableCollection<decimal> distinctPkgIdList = new ObservableCollection<decimal>();
guPackgIds.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(i => distinctPkgIdList.Add(i));

// distinctPkgIdList - ObservableCollection
// guPackgIds.Distinct() - IEnumerable
```

Answer (score 1):

The C# Function to Convert the IEnumerable to ObservableCollection

```
private ObservableCollection<dynamic> IEnumeratorToObservableCollection(IEnumerable source)
    {

        ObservableCollection<dynamic> SourceCollection = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>();

        IEnumerator enumItem = source.GetEnumerator();
        var gType = source.GetType();
        string collectionFullName = gType.FullName;
        Type[] genericTypes = gType.GetGenericArguments();
        string className = genericTypes[0].Name;
        string classFullName = genericTypes[0].FullName;
        string assName = (classFullName.Split('.'))[0];

        // Get the type contained in the name string
        Type type = Type.GetType(classFullName, true);

        // create an instance of that type
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        List<PropertyInfo> oProperty = instance.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
        while (enumItem.MoveNext())
        {

            Object instanceInner = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var x = enumItem.Current;

            foreach (var item in oProperty)
            {
                if (x.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name) != null)
                {
                    var propertyValue = x.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(x, null);
                    if (propertyValue != null)
                    {
                        PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(item.Name);
                        prop.SetValue(instanceInner, propertyValue, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            SourceCollection.Add(instanceInner);
        }

        return SourceCollection;
    }
```

Comment: Very useful!!! Thanks. But it needs two improvements: 1) call it with `this IEnumerable<T> source, string assemblyFullyQualifiedName` and do a `Type type = Type.GetType(           classFullName + $", {assemblyFullyQualifiedName}")`; 2) only SetValue if you can; so instead of `if (propertyValue != null)` do a `if (propertyValue != null && item.CanWrite)`