# ObjectQuery to return object where a child object contains a set value

Tags: c#, linq, objectquery

I have two classes, as follows:

```
public class Route
{
    public ObservableCollection<Flight> Flights = new ObservableCollection<Flight>();
}

public class Flight
{
    string airlineName;
}
```

I wish to return a list of all **routes** that have a flight that is operated by a specified airline.

I tried doing `Routes.SelectMany(x => x.Flights).Where(x => x.Airline == airline);` but that returns all the flight objects - I need the route objects...

Can anyone explain how I can do this using ObjectQuery? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both your classes deal with Flights, so I don't see anywhere where you are getting route information where are you assigning routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Routes.Where(x =>x.Flights.Any(p=> p.Airline == airline))
```

Comment: thanks, that works and returns the expected rresult, however I am getting the following error: `Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[Route]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[Route]'.`

Comment: well, if I do `var result = ` then it works, and if I debug the `result` variable contains a collection of routes, as expected. But I need this in a function which returns a `ObservableCollection<Classes.Route>` - but casting to this fails with the error mentioned

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559821/how-to-convert-ienumerable-to-observablecollection

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. For reference, the returned object is a generic IEnumerable, so to convert to an ObservableCillection all you need is:

`ObservableCollection<Classes.Route> collection = new ObservableCollection<Classes.Route>(result);` (where result is the result of the query in the original answer)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want:

```
Routes.Where(route => route.Flights.Any(flight => flight.Airline == airline))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately RedHat's fingers were quicker, so I will accept his based on being first.

Comment: @GavinCoates: According to the timestamps, I actually posted the answer 31 seconds before RedHat, but I don't mind :)