# How to have a IEnumerable<T>.ToObservableCollection()?

Tags: c#, wpf

I know I can create a `List<T>` from `IEnumerable<T>` by doing 
`myEnumerableCollection.ToList()`, but how could I implement the same thing for an `ObservableCollection<T>` ?

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559821/how-to-convert-ienumerable-to-observablecollection

Comment: Why do you guys expect upvotes from him since you downvote the question?

Comment: that's not a "cast", you're actually creating a new `List<T>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is extension methods.

You can extend the [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) type like this:

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
    public static class LinqExtensions
    {
       public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> _LinqResult)
       {
          return new ObservableCollection<T>(_LinqResult);              
       }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the using directive in classes you want to use this in (i.e: `using myNameSpace;`)

Answer (score 5):

Why would you need to cast it?  That's syntactic sugar for common operations.

```
var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>(regularCollection);
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
 List<string> ll = new List<string> { "a", "b","c" };
 ObservableCollection<string> oc = new ObservableCollection<string>(ll);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new ObservableCollection instance populated with your collection (IEnumerable).