# Cannot convert type IEnumerable to ObservableCollection...are you missing a cast?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-4, filter

I'm trying to return entities where the bool "isAssy" is true:

```
 public ObservableCollection<MasterPartsList> ParentAssemblyBOM
 {
      get {return this._parentAssemblyBOM.Where(parent => parent.isAssy == true); }
 }
```

but the entire statement is underlined in red stating that I cannot "convert type IEnumerable to ObservableCollection...are you missing a cast?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert IEnumerable to ObservableCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559821/how-to-convert-ienumerable-to-observablecollection)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<T>` has an [overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx) that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` as a parameter.  Assuming that your Linq statement returns a collection of `MasterPartsList` items:

```
public ObservableCollection<MasterPartsList> ParentAssemblyBOM
{
    get 
    {
        var enumerable = this._parentAssemblyBOM
                             .Where(parent => parent.isAssy == true);

        return new ObservableCollection<MasterPartsList>(enumerable); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that. Great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly create the ObservableCollection which at it's most simplest is:

```
public ObservableCollection<MasterPartsList> ParentAssemblyBOM
{
    get {return new ObservableCollection<MasterPartsList>(this._parentAssemblyBOM.Where(parent => parent.isAssy == true)); }
}
```

This is potentially inefficient as you are creating new collection every time. However, this might be the simplest solution if you are returning a radically different set of data each time. Otherwise you have to loop through the collection removing items that are no longer in the return set and adding new items.

Comment: I wasn't aware. What is my alternative? Thanks!

Comment: @UB3571 - I'm just checking but it depends on your usage.

Comment: It might be worth the overhead if the collection really does have to be an Observable one.

Comment: I believe the collection must be Observable. I'm binding to the collection in a `ListBox` and the properties of each item in the collection must be fully exposed/implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`