# Filter an ObservableCollection of object C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to filter an `ObservableCollection` of `Person` object by name for my Xamarin Form application.
The goal is to filter this `ObservableCollection` to just display a part of it.

Here is my Person object class :

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to make a filter like this :

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> personItems = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonItems
{
    get { return personItems; }
    set { personItems = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}

public void FilterPerson(string filter)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
    {
        PersonItems = personItems;
    }
    else 
    {
        PersonItems = personItems.Where((person) => person. Name.ToLower().Contains(filter));
        // Error here
    }
}
```

I have this error :

> Cannot not explicitly convert type :
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection

Comment: An observable collection is observable. you should remove unwanted items instead of replacing the complete collection with a new collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot convert type IEnumerable to ObservableCollection...are you missing a cast?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968948/cannot-convert-type-ienumerable-to-observablecollection-are-you-missing-a-cast)

Comment: there is also most likely missing code 'personItems = ', otherwise the error wouldnt appear.

Comment: try using CollectinoViewSource

Comment: thanks @mikus I forgot it when copy paste the code

Comment: Never recreate the collection from new.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41NiKhFxYb0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PersonItems = personItems.Where((person) => person. Name.ToLower().Contains(filter));
```

is returning IEnumerable.

replace it with `PersonItems = new ObservableCollection<Person>(personItems.Where((person) => person.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter)));`

You have to recreate the observable using the filtered results.

Comment: This completely beats the whole purpose of using ObservableCollection i.e. getting events out of it when things change so UI can react to the exact set of changes.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen care to share your insights on alternative method instead of just downvoting an accepted answer?

Comment: You should never have to recreate your observable collection

Comment: Sometimes updating the ObservableCollection is too expensive (high number of items bound to UI, UI flickers and/or becomes unresponsive) and recreation is the right approach. Besides, noone has provided a better way of filtering ObservableCollection (short of reverting to using ICollectionView)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, there are two solutions:

1. If your PersonsItems list is not huge, you may recreate a whole collection each time a new filter string arrives. You don't even need an ObservableCollection in this case (due to the fact that you don't change the collection itself, you change a reference to a collection). All the UI elements will be recreated in this case

   ```
   PersonItems = originalItems.Where((person) => person. Name.ToLower().Contains(filter)).ToList();
   ```
2. If your PersonsItems list is big enough, the first solution is not an option. In this case you need to manually call Add/Remove methods on the objects that should be added/removed. ObservableCollection has an imperative API and it fires an event each time Add/Remove is called. This event, in turn, can be observed by the ItemsControl that will make corresponding UI changes. Linq has a declarative API. That's why u need to sync a list to show with a filtered list manually.

Comment: As it was suggested above, you can also use a CollectionView that supports filtering.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, but the first solution is not working, the the or not the same why ?

Comment: As I wrote, for the first approach you don't need an ObservableCollection. Just change PersonItems property/backing field type to List<Person> and use the assignment mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in the past I've used James Montemagno's ObservableRangeCollection and Grouping helper functions. You can find them in this plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers

Comment: Good idea I use this plugin too