# Linq filtering in a property's getter

Tags: c#, linq, error-handling, implicit-conversion

Is it possible to filter an `ObservableCollection` within a property? I have tried variations of the following:

```
public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers
{
    get { return DataManager.Data.MasterWorkerList.Where(w => w.Known == true); }
    set { DataManager.Data.MasterWorkerList = value; }
}
```

I get an error that says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

When I cast the type, the program compiles, but I get an `InvalidCastException` saying

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[AoW.Models.Worker]' to type
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[AoW.Models.Worker]'

Is it possible to filter this way? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert IEnumerable to ObservableCollection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559821/how-to-convert-ienumerable-to-observablecollection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to convert `IEnumerable<Worker>` to `ObservableCollection<Worker>`. You can do this by  passing your `IEnumerable` into the constructor of the `ObservableCollection` when you create a new one as below:

```
 return  new ObservableCollection<Worker>(DataManager.Data.MasterWorkerList.Where(w => w.Known == true));
```

You can make your code more readable by defining an extension method . This can be done as:

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
   if (source == null)
   {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
   }
   return new ObservableCollection<T>(source);
}
```

Thusly, your code would become very simple and readable

```
public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers
{
    get 
    { 
       var workerList = DataManager.Data.MasterWorkerList.Where(w => w.Known == true);
       return workerList.ToObservableCollection<Worker>();
    }
    set 
    { 
       DataManager.Data.MasterWorkerList = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, for some reason this causes the UI to not update according to changes in the `ObservableColection`.

Comment: But the answer is correct.Its further your issue..please consider putting another question for it

Comment: Fair enough. Still though, do you have any ideas on how to use this solution and have the UI be able to update?

Comment: Use fresh instance of `DataManager.Data.` each time

Comment: It's a Singleton class. I made it that way so that I could access its contents throughout the entire project and to avoid having to limit data to my viewmodels.

Comment: I just started programming a couple months ago (this is my first actual project) so I'm still learning the ropes. I was just looking for a way to store data in a centralized and easily accessible location and I didn't know of a better way to do it.