# how to filter data from DataServiceCollection ? in WCF data service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, windows-store-apps, wcf-data-services

I got data in **DataServiceCollection** EquipBookings , but from this list i want to filter data , as per date selected from data picker

for this i try to write this, but it is not working  :

i got error "cannnot implicity convert type list to Dataservicecollection

```
  private DateTime _seletedDateChanged;
        public DateTime SeletedDateChanged
        {
            get { return _seletedDateChanged; }
            private set
            {
                _seletedDateChanged = value; 

                         // here i filter collections

                EquipBookings = FilterJobs(_seletedDateChanged);
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SeletedDateChanged");
            }
        }

        public DataServiceCollection<EquipBooking> FilterJobs(DateTime SeletedDateChanged)
        {
            return EquipBookings.Where(c => c.CreatedOn == SeletedDateChanged).ToList();
        }
```

Full code is :

```
        #region EquipBookings
        // Define the binding collection for EquipBookings.
        private DataServiceCollection<EquipBooking> _equipBookings;

        public DataServiceCollection<EquipBooking> EquipBookings
        {
            get { return _equipBookings; }
            private set
            {
                _equipBookings = value;
                _equipBookings.LoadCompleted += OnEquipBookingLoaded;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("EquipBookings");
            }
        }
        public void LoadEquipBookingsData()
        {
            _context = new THA001_devEntities(_rootUri);
            EquipBookings = new DataServiceCollection<EquipBooking>(_context);
            var query = _context.EquipBooking.Expand("Status").Where(x => x.Status.Description.ToLower() == "confirmed").OrderBy(d => d.BookedFromDteTme);
            EquipBookings.LoadAsync(query);
            IsDataLoaded = true;
        }

        private void OnEquipBookingLoaded(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                IsDataLoaded = false;
                if (EquipBookings.Continuation != null)
                {
                    EquipBookings.LoadNextPartialSetAsync();
                    EquipBookingList = EquipBookings;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a list:

```
return EquipBookings.Where(c => c.CreatedOn == SeletedDateChanged).ToList();
```

While the return type of your `FilterJobs` method is `DataServiceCollection<EquipBooking>` and there's no implicit conversion between the two. The compiler doesn't understand how to convert one to the other.

You could do something like this:

```
public DataServiceCollection<EquipBooking> FilterJobs(DateTime SeletedDateChanged)
    {
        var equipBookings = EquipBookings.Where(c => c.CreatedOn == SeletedDateChanged);
        var dataServiceCollection = new DataServiceCollection<EquipBooking>(equipBookings);

        return dataServiceCollection;

    }
```

There's a constructor overload of `DataServiceCollection` that takes an `IEnumerable{T}` (an `IEnumerable` of `EquipBookings` in your case) as a parameter. Conveniently this is exactly what the `EquipBookings.Where(c => c.CreatedOn == SeletedDateChanged);` returns.

Comment: i got error : An item could not be added to the collection. When items in a DataServiceCollection are tracked by the DataServiceContext, new items cannot be added before items have been loaded into the collection.

Comment: @vb1 Changed the example. Could you try that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert generic IEnumerable to ObservableCollection. You can write an extension method to do this conversion. Examples are given here as well [How to convert IEnumerable to ObservableCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559821/how-to-convert-ienumerable-to-observablecollection)