# remove duplicate from ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<DateTime> myItems`

and it has some duplicate items that needs to be removed

I tried using :

```
myItems = myItems.Distinct();
```

however i can't build it and recieve this error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

and when I check the ObservableCollection I find that it is `IEnumerable<T>` as the following Go to Definition shows:

```
public class ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged

public class Collection<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

so I tried to cast as following :

```
myItems = (ObservableCollection<DateTime>) myItems.Distinct();
```

it build fine without error; but at runtime it throws the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'd__81`1[System.DateTime]' to type
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.DateTime]'.

I also tried the following:

```
myItems = (ObservableCollection<DateTime>) myItems.Distinct().toList<DateTime>();
```

but then I reeive the following compile time error:

> Error 1   Cannot convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'

what I am missing here?
and how can I remove the duplicate items from the ObservableCollection ?

Comment: Project a new Observable collection using the `IEnumerable` constructor: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3559821/314291

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
myItems = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>(myItems.Distinct());
```

Answer (score 3):

well you are missing the fact that, `Distinct` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, which is not an `ObservableCollection`. And `ToList` returns a `List<T>` which is not an `ObservableCollection` either.

Those types are not convertible to `ObservableCollection`, so you can't cast them directly. You need to create a new `ObservableCollection` and populate it with new items.

You can do that using the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms658737%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `ObservableCollection<T>`, or you can also implement your own method (if you like to use fluent syntax of linq):

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(
       this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
     var collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();

     foreach(var item in source)
          collection.Add(item);

     return collection;
}
```

Comment: your explanation is great .. but i was fooled by the error message , it was misleading [ An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)].. so all my search was about the [missing cast] :(

Comment: @stackunderflow if there is no implicit conversion defined between the types, than compiler will suggest you to cast it explicitly, if that isn't possible either then, it will throw `InvalidCastException` at runtime like in your example :)