# How to sort ObservableCollection alphabetically?

Tags: c#, sorting

I need to sort an `ObservableCollection` after populatior alphabetically, suppose that inside I've this model:

```
class Nation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my `ObservableCollection`:

```
ObservableCollection<Nation> ob = new ObservableCollection<Nation>();
```

suppose that inside I've three items with this order:

1. England
2. Afghanistan
3. Italy

I need to sort it alphabetically, so I tried to:

```
ob.OrderBy(c => c.Name);
```

but I get no effect, when it should be:

1. Afghanistan
2. England
3. Italy

What I did wrong?

Comment: You have to assign the result to something, it returns a sorted collection. `var sortedOb = ob.OrderBy(c => c.Name);`

Comment: @Igor so should be: `ob = ob.OrderBy(c => c.Name);`?

Comment: You would have to convert it back to an `ObservableCollection<T>` as `OrderBy` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @Igor I though that `.OrderBy` reorder the original collection, instead of return new one.

Comment: @AgainMe Every LINQ method generates a new enumerable instead of modifying the original one

Comment: @AgainMe No - it returns an _iterator_ that wrpas the original collection, returning their elements in the specified order _when you loop over it_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> bind your `ObservableCollection` to a `CollectionViewsource`, add a sort
>   on it, then use that `CollectionViewSource` as the `ItemSource` of a
>   Control.

Use CollectionViewSource to Sort

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key='src' Source="{Binding ob}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
 </CollectionViewSource>
```

Sample usage

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource src}}" >
```

Comment: Best solution, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
var ob = new ObservableCollection<Nation>
{
    new Nation {Name = "Sweden"},
    new Nation {Name = "Afghanistan"},
    new Nation {Name = "England"},
    new Nation {Name = "Albania"},
};

var sorted = ob.OrderBy(n => n.Name);
```

`sorted` is `IEnumerable` and sorted, if you still need it as `ObservableCollection` just pass it to the constructor as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559821/how-to-convert-ienumerable-to-observablecollection).