# How can I cast a list to an observablecollection in c#?

Tags: c#, list, casting, observablecollection

I have a List that I want to cast to an `ObservableCollection`, this is my code

```
var list = Models.Lands.FromJson(responce.Result.ToString());
this.Lands = new ObservableCollection<Land>( list );
```

`FromJson` returns me a `List<Models.Land>`, and this.Lands is an `ObservableCollection<Models.Land>`.

`new ObservableCollection<Models.Land>( list )` gives me the following error:

> cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<> to
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>,

I thought that the constructor was overloaded for a List<> object.

Comment: What are they types given in your error? A `List<T>` can be converted to an `IEnumerable<T>` so presumably your generic objects are of different types but you seem to have stripped out this crucial information...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert IEnumerable to ObservableCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559821/how-to-convert-ienumerable-to-observablecollection)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the nongeneric var keyword.

```
List<Land> list =Models.Lands.FromJson(responce.Result.ToString());
var collection = new ObservableCollection<Land>(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like below to avoid your problem but still using a single line of code:

```
this.Lands = new ObservableCollection<Land>( list.ToArray<Land>());
```

but I'm not sure if that's an efficient way to do that.

Comment: Why ToArray? The ObservableCollection constructor takes an IEnumerable so there is no need to copy all list elements to an array which is then copied to the ObservableCollection.

Comment: I agree with you, but i encounter the same error times ago and without the "toArray" you got the error, with it the error disappear...  The difference is that in Observable collection you're casting a Lands[] instead of  List<Land>, but i agree that both should be converted into IEnumerable without any problem.

Answer (score -1):

Works in my browser: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VVB8YY

```
public static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<String>{"a", "b", "c"};
    var collection = new ObservableCollection<string>(list);

    foreach (var value in collection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```