# WP7 Insert all linq results in an ObservableCollection

Tags: binding, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7

I parse an xml results from a webservice using linq :

```
XElement items = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
MyListBox.ItemsSource = from item in items.Descendants("node")
            select new MyViewModel
            {
               ...
            };
```

This automatically populate my ListBox. But the problem is, I usually access my ObservableCollection like this :

```
App.MyViewModel.MyItems;
```

having in my xaml :

```
ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems,}"
```

How can I modify directly my ObservableCollection ? I read [Cast LINQ result to ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465285/cast-linq-result-to-observablecollection)
 and tried this :

```
var v = from item in items.Descendants("node")
            select new MyViewModel
            {
               ...
            };
OApp.MyViewModel.MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>(v);
```

But I can't since this in WP7 (Silverlight 3), and there is no constructor like this

Thanks !

Comment: Note (in case you didn't know): if you are just displaying the items (without adding/removing) then you don't need to use an ObservableCollection. An IEnumerable will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just invent a static method like this:-

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> CreateObservableCollect<T>(IEnumerable<T> range)
{
    var result = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    foreach (T item in range)
    {
        result.Add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now your last line of code becomes:-

```
 OApp.MyViewModel.MyItems = new CreateObservableCollection<MyViewModel>(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you're trying to use is in Silverlight, just not available on the phone. (as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms658737%28v=VS.95%29.aspx))

Unfortunately, you'll have to populate your ObservableCollection yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need ObservableCollection? Do you need add or delete objects from collection or just update?

If only update, you can change MyViewModel.MyItems to:

```
public MyTypeOfCollection MyItems
{
    get { return _myItems; }
    set
    {
        _myItems = value;
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("MyItems");//invoke INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    }
}
```

If you need adding or deleting of items, you can extend your collection to:

```
public static class Extend
{
    // Extend ObservableCollection<T> Class
    public static void AddRange(this System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection o, T[] items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            o.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```