# WPF Binding to collection with constraint

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have an observable collection of objects.
I wish to bind a gridview to this observable collection. But there is a constraint that only objects whose property x has value a, must be binded

How to do that?

I got it working using CollectionView and filter. For others benefit the code is as follows

**Solution :**

```
public class CustomerViewModel
    {       
       public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
       {
           get;
           set;
       }


       private ICollectionView _filteredCustomerView;
       public ICollectionView FilteredCustomers
       {
           get { return _filteredCustomerView; }
       }


       public CustomerViewModel()
       {
           this.Customers= new ObservableCollection<Customer>();               
           Customers= GetCustomer();
           _filteredCustomerView= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Customers);
           _filteredCustomerView.Filter = MyCustomFilter;

       }


       private bool MyCustomFilter(object item)
       {
           Customer cust = item as Customer;
           return (cust.Location == "someValue");

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use [filtering](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/luc/archive/2009/01/14/sorts-and-filters-on-observablecollection.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using LINQ.

```
var result = YourCollection.Where(p => p.x.HasValue).ToObservableCollection();
```

But you should write your own [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465285/cast-linq-result-to-observablecollection/1465299#1465299) to convert to ObservableCollection.

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>
              (this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    return new ObservableCollection<T>(source);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: But changes in the source collection won't propagate to the result collection, so updates won't reflect in the UI automatically. Using the CollectionView and filter avoids that.

Comment: That extension method is just a wrapper for 'new'.  Seems like overkill.

Comment: @mancaus: I agree, but I thought of reassign the new result as a datasource. I know it's not tuned, but with small amount of data it's OK and easier to deal.

Comment: @Ed S: Yes, It's just a wrapper, but it'll be more readable. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this in XAML by putting a DataTrigger on the style of your GridView. Something like this:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFiltered}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFiltered}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```