# How to sort/filter observable collection and get back observable collection not IEnumerable

Tags: c#, collections

Can any one please guide me which is best way to sort/filter observable collection and get back observable collection not IEnumerable ?

Comment: Well, how are you sorting the observable collection right now?

Comment: @BoltClock : I am not sorting right now as I have not much idea about it. I found OrderBy() method but it returns IEnumerable.

Comment: @Richard: He's probably talking about ObservableCollection.

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari: I'm assuming this is about `ObservableCollection`. Do you want the collection itself to be sorted or do you want the view to be sorted (assuming the collection is hooked up to a view)?

Comment: I need collection itself cause I had implemented notify event handler on it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably for the sort you can convert it to a List and then call Sort(), providing a comparison delegate. Something like:-

my_collection.ToList().Sort((left, right) => left == right ? 0 : (left > right ? -1 : 1));

Comment: I need ObservableCollection in return, not List.

Answer (score 1):

If the result of sorting/filtering is `IEnumerable<T>` then you can just create another `ObservableCollection` and pass result as a parameter to constructor

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465285/cast-linq-result-to-observablecollection)

Comment: But in that example, it creates new observable collection, if I assign my collection by this way then notify event will not fire for binded source.

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari can you just use this new collection as a data source? or you want to add/delete/move every element in you initial list while sorting and notify your UI about that?

Comment: I can't bind new source again cause I have lots of data and it will takes too much time to bind it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at my `ObservableView` implementation which wraps an observable collection (or other list) and provides "live" ordering and filtering:

https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ObservableView