# convert linq results of decimal to ObservableCollection<string>

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to store results from a LINQ query into ObservableCollection but the results from linq are of decimal type.

```
ObservableCollection<string> cost = 
    new ObservableCollection<string>((from i in context.Items
                                      where i.Cost != null
                                      && i.Cost > 0
                                      orderby i.Cost
                                      select i.Cost).Distinct());
```

It doesn't compile saying `'The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>.ObservableCollection(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>)' has some invalid arguments.`

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465285/cast-linq-result-to-observablecollection) but it didn't help me much.

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following with no success:

```
ObservableCollection<string> cost = 
new ObservableCollection<string>((from i in context.Items
                                  where i.Cost != null
                                     && i.Cost > 0
                                  orderby i.Cost
                                  select i.Cost).Distinct()
                                                .Select(i=>i.ToString()));
```

and

```
ObservableCollection<string> cost = 
new ObservableCollection<string>((from i in context.Items
                                  where i.Cost != null
                                  && i.Cost > 0
                                  orderby i.Cost
                                  select i.Cost.ToString()).Distinct());
```

When I run both in LINQPad, I get the following error:
`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. 
Message LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ObservableCollection<string> cost = 
    new ObservableCollection<string>((from i in context.Items
                                      where i.Cost != null
                                      && i.Cost > 0
                                      orderby i.Cost
                                      select i.Cost).Distinct()
                                                    .AsEnumerable()
                                                    .Select(c => c.ToString()));
```

Since apparently the EF provider can't seem translate the `ToString()` call into SQL, putting in a call to `AsEnumerable()` will bring the query into memory and the `ToString()` call will use LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 2):

Convert `Cost` to a string with `ToString`:

```
ObservableCollection<string> cost = 
    new ObservableCollection<string>((from i in context.Items
                                      where i.Cost != null
                                      && i.Cost > 0
                                      orderby i.Cost
                                      select i.Cost.ToString()).Distinct());
```

Use whatever `CultureInfo` you need, if any, when calling `ToString()`.

Answer (score 2):

Do the `ToString` **after** the `Distinct`. That way it's not creating so many strings and comparing those strings in the distinct.

```
ObservableCollection<string> cost = 
    new ObservableCollection<string>((from i in context.Items
                                      where i.Cost != null
                                         && i.Cost > 0
                                      orderby i.Cost
                                      select i.Cost).Distinct()
                                                    .Select(i=>i.ToString()));
```

Comment: I tried this out but it crashes silently when I run it.  If I put a breakpoint on it and try to step-in/over it, the program just continues running and skips the rest of the code (as in the form loads up but there is nothing in the collection).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use ToString()?

```
ObservableCollection<string> cost = 
    new ObservableCollection<string>((from i in context.Items
                                  where i.Cost != null
                                  && i.Cost > 0
                                  orderby i.Cost
                                  select i.Cost.ToString()).Distinct());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should select string values from `context.Items` to create an `ObservableCollection<string>` by casting them to `String`

```
ObservableCollection<string> cost = 
    new ObservableCollection<string>((from i in context.Items
                                      where i.Cost != null
                                      && i.Cost > 0
                                      orderby i.Cost
                                      select i.Cost.ToString()).Distinct());
```

Or create an `ObservableCollection<decimal>`

```
ObservableCollection<decimal> cost = 
    new ObservableCollection<decimal>((from i in context.Items
                                      where i.Cost != null
                                      && i.Cost > 0
                                      orderby i.Cost
                                      select i.Cost).Distinct());
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion but I get the same results as I commented on in Weston's post.  I can't use the decimal ObservableCollection unfortunately.